# MySQL LIKE query is not worked for search record with apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql

when i start searching a record from db i got an issue when apostrophes present in word
for that i used addslashes,mysql_real_escape_strin  but not worked for that

```
<?php
    include("lib/dbconn.php");
    $list_query_main1="select * from table where name like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['keyword'])."%'";
   $list=mysql_query($list_query_main1);
   echo mysql_num_rows($list);
?>
```

Zero results found but name present in DB give me solution.

Comment: Could you please echo `$list_query_main1` and post the result

Comment: select * from table where name like '%Baker\'s%'

Answer (score 1):

you are getting mysql error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' at line 1
```

because TABLE is reserved word. If you named your table like TABLE, you must use right mysql syntax

```
$list_query_main1="select * from `table` where `name` like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['keyword'])."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `if(!$list || mysql_errno() != 0) echo mysql_error();` after line `$list=mysql_query($list_query_main1);` will give you some info in case of a query failure

Otherwise myqsl_* is deprecated you should start using mysqli_* functions.

And change your last line

```
echo $mysql_num_rows($list);
```

and replace it with

```
echo mysql_num_rows($list);
```

If you want to call myqsl_num_rows() function